# Vetor com loop não atualiza valores

Tags: c, array, algoritmo

Estou tentando criar um vetor com step size de 0.1. No Matlab ficaria da seguinte forma `h = 0:0.1:1;`. Tentei em C da seguinte forma, mas o vetor não atualiza, permanece em zero:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    float h[10];
     
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        h[i+1] = h[i] + 0.1;
        printf("h = %2f\n", h);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem vários erros... Começa que não tem nada em `h[0]`, que seria usado logo na primeira soma. E depois você tenta acessar h[10] quando i chega a 9, e não existe h[10]. E você tenta imprimir o vetor todo de uma vez, o que não é possível. https://ideone.com/rXOxYG

Comment: No `printf()` falta o índice `i`. E falta o valor inicial para `h[0]`. E não pode ir até `h[10]`: só tem 10, não 11

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Não dá para transpor algo de uma linguagem para outra sem adaptar.

Precisa inicializar o elemento 0 do *array*, o erro deve estar aí.

Aí começa fazer o laço do elemento 1 e não do 0, até porque é mais fácil que ficar manipulando o índice em todo lugar. Até porque ele é necessário para ficar melhor.

Ainda tinha o erro de não imprimir cada elemento dentro do laço e sim tentar imprimir o*array*, que na verdade é um endereço.

Sugiro aprender C antes e fazer os códigos. É uma linguagem que exige bastante conhecimento de como o computador funciona, não vem tudo pronto.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    float h[10];
    h[0] = 0;
    printf("h[0] = %.2f\n", h[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        h[i] = h[i - 1] + 0.1;
        printf("h[%d] = %.2f\n", i, h[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Tr8Q2a). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/gktyyjvjdl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ArrayIncrement.c).

Answer (score -1):

apesar dos erros , o que precisa mesmo para que esse código funcione é colocar esses colchetes com a variavel    i    dentro dele na função printf :

```
printf("h = %2f\n", h[i]);
```